# Accessing dynamic input text fields

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, input, radio-button, controls

I have a page with a number of dynamic RadiobuttonLists for users to select. Sometimes, there are textboxes next to the ListItems of each RadiobuttonList.

E.g.

(o) Listitem [textbox]

(o) Listitem2

(o) Listitem3 [textbox]

The way I coded is (pseudo code):

```
Foreach RadiobuttonList

RadioButtonList radioOption = new RadioButtonList();

name = "inputName" + i.ToString();    

radioOption.Items.Add(new ListItem("ListItem" + " <input id=\"" + name + "\" name=\"name\" type=\"text\" value=\"Enter text\" />"))
```

My question is, since the input textboxes are declared/created this way, how do I access the text the users enter in each of these textboxes?

How do I loop through all the input boxes and print out the details entered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any inputs that are submitted to a Page can be accessed from the `Request.Form` collection.

You can get the value as follws:

```
var name = "inputName" + i.ToString();  
var listItemValue = Request.Form[name];
```

Comment: Thanks - but it doesnt work for me. The var listItemValue always returns as null. I am running my codes to create these dynamic controls at onInit...maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Controls should always be created on `Init`. However you can get the values only after `Load`.

Comment: Any ideas why my Request.Form[name] always return null
after I enter the textbox (next to the radiobutton)?